# Wordpress - "Remove item from cart / Empty cart" functions not always working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have a Wordpress - Woocommerce cart mini float tab with 2 functions:

1. The possibility to remove one single item from the cart
2. The possibility to empty the cart with one click

My first problem is that the "remove one item" function sometimes works well, sometimes empties the entire cart.

My second problem is that the "empty cart button" sometimes works well, sometimes needs to be clicked twice to work.

I can't understand how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You may apply my bellow logic to remove items one by one when it is grater then 1 and empty cart when value is 1.
Here 'id' is the product id.
cart name is "scart".
qty is the items quantity.

```
$max=count($_SESSION['scart']['id']); // count all id within your cart
                $id=$_POST['id']; // this id is your deletaion operation product id after click. 
                for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
                    if($id==$_SESSION['scart']['id'][$i]){
                        if($_SESSION['scart']['qty'][$i]>1){
                            $pos=$_SESSION['scart']['id'][$i];
                            $cart["qty"][$i]=$cart["qty"][$i]-1;
                            $_SESSION["scart"]=$cart;

                        } else{
                            unset($_SESSION['scart']['id'][$i]);
                            unset($_SESSION['scart']['qty'][$i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind help @Mrinmoy Majee, I'll try to apply it  to my code!

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your functionality by using following hooks :

```
woocommerce_before_mini_cart
woocommerce_after_mini_cart
woocommerce_before_cart
woocommerce_after_cart
```